# How to automate Google App Engine update with gradle plugin and Jenkins

Tags: google-app-engine, jenkins, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm having trouble configuring my gradle build for continous deployment to Google App Engine.
I've set up a service account for this purpose but I cannot see where to configure it in the gradle script. Ultimately I want to set this up in Jenkins so this process needs to be totally automated.

Below is an extract from my build.gradle file (with credentials removed) where I'm trying to configure this.

```
appengine {

        httpPort = 8888

        downloadSdk = true

        appcfg {
            email = "the service account email goes here"
            noCookies
            oauth2 = true
        }

    }
```

This works fine with manual authentication but I cannot figure out how to do this automatically.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking... you're saying that currently using your build asks you to manually authenticate? You are aware you use "no cookies", which means "go through the oauth flow every time"? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin

Comment: I've tried that and it works if I authenticate manually once from the server. It also doesn't use the service account. I guess it's ok but it would be better if my build server could authenticate its self with the service account secret key file.

Comment: Well looking into the link I gave, seems like the only way to fully automate with an email is to add "password" in your fields. Since service accounts don't have these, I don't really see how you could do it with just the key file :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin) on the plugin, the only way to not ask for a manual authorization is to pass the "password" of the account in your parameters. Since your service account doesn't have a password, it unfortunately won't be possible to do it this way

Comment: While this is true, does it not defeat the concept of a service account? Or am I missing the point?

Comment: @jamespercy from https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount, service accounts are meant for "server to server auth", not client to server, so it's actually working as intended I'd say

Comment: I guess I misunderstood what they meant by "server to server".